# Track GPS data for a certain time with Python

Tags: python, api, gps, android-gps, gpsd

I want to create a fitness program using python.

When the user creates a account in my program he/she needs to have the option to select the location of their gym or the place where they workout. So in other words, a map opens up and the user has to find the place where they workout and mark it.

Then, I want to use the GPS of their phones in order to look if they were at least 30 minutes inside a 30 meter radius from the mark (their gym, or other place where they workout) in 24 hours.
If they were, I want to count that day.

My questions are:

1. Is this thing even possible?
2. Is python the best programing language for this or should I use something else?
3. Is there any library for Python that can help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you planning on making a phone app for iOS/Android?

Since you said you maps on their phone, I am assuming you mean a phone app.

I would suggest learning Objective-C, if you are trying to make apps for iOS specifically, and the preferred language of implementation for Android would be Java.

With that said, you absolutely can use python to develop an Android or iOS app with something like [BeeWare](https://beeware.org/)! Which is a nice suite of python tools so you can build your program from the ground up with pure python.

So there are many options with advantages/disadvantages; everyone will give their two sense on which is the best way to approach, but I would suggest researching the many ways phone apps are developed to get your feet wet and get familiar with the process before going head first at those additional questions!

It is a bit different than writing a python program on your computer, running it on command prompt/terminal and being good to go!